# SQL Server 2008 R2 and Check Constraints

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and for my prototype I want to input a bunch of historical data, then I would like to put in a constraint such as

```
ProductionDate >= GETDATE()
```

but I cannot save it after I do this, since the system will not alter the tables after the historical data fails the check.

What do I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a constraint is to prevent invalid data. Either remove your historical data and place it in a backup table or update it so that the constraint is honoured; You will have to do the validation on your front end otherwise.

Another alternative is to have an Archive flag and incorporate that into your constraint:

> ProductionDate >= GETDATE() OR Archive = 1